# Google chrome extension returns undefined for any getElement

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I tried writing a pointless chrome extension, but in my content script any of the getElements return undefined.

Here is my manifest.json

```
    {
"name": "xyx",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "xyx",
"permissions":[
    "tabs",
    "bookmarks",
    "activeTab"
],
"content_scripts":[
 {
    "matches":["http://*/*"],
    "js":["func.js"],
    "run_at":"document_end",
    "all_frames":true
 }
]
```

}

and here is my content script

```
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName["href"];
    for(var i = 0; i <= x.length; i++){ 
        x[i].innerHTML = "http://www.facebook.com";
    }
```

For some reason I cant get it to stop returning undefined.Any solution's?

Comment: Generally speaking, you should be able to take a copy of the page's html and put `<script src="func.js"></script>` just before `</body>`.  If that doesn't work, you have a javascript problem, not an extension problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`href` is not a tag, but an attribute. Another issue with the above code is that you should use round brackets `()`, as `var x = document.getElementsByTagName("a");`